# How to get a localized label in ext_tables.php

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I want to get a localized label in the `ext_tables.php` of one of my extensions. I need this value as a php variable.

Is there a clean way of getting it in that place?
The variable

```
$GLOBALS['LANG']
```

is not yet initialized, and using the `LocalizationUtility` from extbase fails, too.

Comment: That's problematic as during reading the cached ext_tables `$GLOBALS['LANG']` neither `$GLOBALS['TSFE']` isn't available, typically in ext_tables you store the keys for translation so they're localized later, just curious what do you want to achieve (maybe there's some workaround)?

Comment: I want to add a wizard icon for one of my plugins, and want to put it into one of the tabs that are generated by EXT:fluidcontent. The names *and* keys of these tabs are localized labels, so I need to set a TSconfig-setting under the key `mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.<localized value here>`. `EXT:fluidcontent` does this not adding the items to the wizard on the first call, instead it waits until localization is available. Then it generates the TSconfig, saves it into a cache, and loads the value from that cache in the `ext_tables.php`.